# Azure Logic app condition step not working properly

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-boards

I want to do automation that when anyone changes *child task state to 'In Progress' their parent i.e. Product backlog Item's state gets update to 'Committed' automatically in azure board.*

To achieve this have tried creating logic app but every time whilst running condition step is getting skipped with status 'Branching condition is not satisfied.

My Logic app designer looks as below

[image]

Here are my steps which am using in logic app.
[image]

[image]

Condition as when task state is in progress and parent is equal to New
[image]

when condition is true then run below step which is not running at the moment

[image]

Error am facing as below
[image]

Here is conditions drop down reference for PBI which am using
[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I created the same workflow as yours, and then encountered the same issue as yours. The "expressionResult" of Condition has always been false. What's interesting is that I created a new workflow with the same actions today, and it worked. Sharing my code with you, you can compare with yours and see if there are any differences.
[image]

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "...",
        "actions": {
            "Condition": {
                "actions": {
                    "Update_a_work_item": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": {
                                "userEnteredFields": {
                                    "System.State": "Committed"
                                }
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "referenceName": "visualstudioteamservices"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "patch",
                            "path": "/_apis/wit/workitems/@{encodeURIComponent(body('Get_work_item_details')?['id'])}",
                            "queries": {
                                "account": "{org name}"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "else": {
                    "actions": {}
                },
                "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "equals": [
                                "@triggerBody()?['fields']?['System_State']",
                                "In Progress"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "equals": [
                                "@body('Get_work_item_details')?['fields']?['System_State']",
                                "New"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_work_item_details": [
                        "SUCCEEDED"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "If"
            },
            "Get_work_item_details": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "referenceName": "visualstudioteamservices"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/_apis/wit/workitems/@{encodeURIComponent(triggerBody()?['fields']?['System_Parent'])}",
                    "queries": {
                        "account": "{org name}",
                        "project": "{project name}",
                        "typeName": "Product Backlog Item"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_work_item_is_updated": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "referenceName": "visualstudioteamservices"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/workitemupdated_trigger/@{encodeURIComponent('{project name}')}/_apis/wit/wiql",
                    "queries": {
                        "account": "{org name}",
                        "wiql__System_WorkItemType": "Task"
                    }
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()?['value']",
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}
```

Comment: @user, have you tried creating a new workflow directly using the code above? Would you please let me know if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Here I am trying to update the Parent Task's state from `Doing to Done` if Child Task's state changes to **Done**.

> To achieve this have tried creating logic app but every time whilst running condition step is getting skipped with status 'Branching condition is not satisfied.

Please verify if your Condition is true, even I got the same error when my condition executed with false.

[image]

Or else verify if `System.State: Committed` is available in your work item dropdown.

[image]

**Workflow:**

[image]

Checking when parent's state is Doing and Child's state is Done, it will return true.

[image]

[image]

**Output:**

My workflow is getting executed successfully and state got changed to Done.

[image]

Please check, if both the fields in Condition action is populating correctly and executed with true status.

Comment: I think conditions are correct and we have committed for Product backlog item state as well not sure where am going wrong

Comment: @user are you getting true after execution

Comment: @user Both the fields should satisfy the condition, if one of them is false then it will get fail

Comment: How can I verify that because in Condition step status is populating as 'Succeeded' however in True action's getting 'branching condition not satisfied'

Comment: Also in **Get Work Item details** step right above the condition am unable to provide Parent like **item()?['fields']?['System_Parent']** as a Work item ID as it throws not found error, so passing actual ID for testing

Comment: @user please share the screenshot of the condition action post execution like [this](https://i.imgur.com/rC5xJUj.png)? You can pass the Parent id using Dynamic content like [this](https://i.imgur.com/Tj8KCGw.png)

Comment: That's what am unable to see true/false status as well. See https://imgur.com/a/J0kdOGV for reference. Also for Parent am giving the same like you suggested https://imgur.com/FvtAfsJ but getting not found error https://imgur.com/vh3Gqii

Comment: Ohh I see, please check your first action **When a work item is updated** output body post execution, you will see parent I'd is null. Because for testing purpose you need to make change in your child work item, then only parent I'd will be passed

Comment: Again can't see the output after step 1 https://imgur.com/lPGpzOQ. However am updating the task states every time before testing in azure boards. Hell! not sure where am wrong

Comment: Refresh the page and the check work item created in project and the project name you have given in logic app is same

Comment: am updating the task state to In progress every time for testing purpose and refreshing the board as well

Comment: Start with one action at a time like create **When a work item is updated** first then test it and check the output likewise add the other actions one by one and parallely test the workflow as well. I would suggest you to start from the scratch and make sure to check the parent I'd field in first actions output body

Comment: Problem is am getting 'Error loading inputs and outputs' so can't see that as well

Comment: @user please check if public access is allowed [here](https://i.imgur.com/UbaUSSf.png)

Comment: Yeah have checked that as well. Here is for your reference. https://imgur.com/a/x9h3Zqa

Comment: @user still you are getting input output loading error? Can you try to create a new workflow and test on it